# Where is my output when debugging C code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a simple c program, with prints something to screen. 
When I debug the program I can see the DEBUG CONSOLE, however as soon as I use fgets I don't see any output. Where does my program run when debugging using VS Code?

If I just run my compiled .exe, everything is printed as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  printf("Enter your name\n");

  char name[100];
  // fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin); // as soon as I uncomment this, no output is in the output console
  printf("You name %s", name);

  return 0;
}
```

my launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(Windows) Launch",
      "type": "cppvsdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you add any breakpoint(s) in the code?

Comment: if I add a breakpoint, it is hit, I can step trough the code, see variables, however the standard input and output are not in the debug pane, which makws sense, because it is readonly window

Comment: Try to reconfigure the `tasks.json` and `launch.json` they might fix your error.

Answer (score 0):

One solution may solve your issue.

### How to configure `tasks.json` and `launch.json` from VSCode

You don't need to do any type of coding for this, just follow the steps:

1. Delete `tasks.json` and `launch.json` located in `.vscode` folder
2. Press `F5` (debugging shortcut) again focusing on that C program file, you'll see something like:

[image: Automatic launch configuration wizard]

3. Select your compiler which is `GCC` (since you're trying to debug a C program and ensure the compiler is installed into your system).
4. You'll be prompted to select a configuration (assuming selected option: GCC), you'll get `launch.json` created automatically by VSCode as shown below:

[image: Successful creation of launch.json]

> **Note:** Keep the `preLaunchTask` configuration in your mind (located at the bottom-most of the config).

5. As soon as you press `F5` again (this time, for creation of `tasks.json`) you'll get something shown below, simply select **Configure Tasks**:

[image: Required error to configure tasks.json]

6. Now, you'll be redirected into `tasks.json`, edit the `label` to the name you've selected in § 4 (remember that `name`). In other words, launch's `preLaunchTask` and tasks' `label` should be the same. Process shown below:

[image: Renaming the label for debugging]

And now, you can make a successful debug. A working example:

[image: A successful example of debugging]

Comment: Could you post entire tasks.json and launch.json? I'm not using gcc.exe and you have mentioned prelaunchtask which is not visible at all.

Comment: What are you using then?

Comment: @Liero [there](https://filebin.net/q4f9n1rkixe5jfsf) you go. (The zip only contains tasks and launch.json). Don't forget to configure with your own settings or it might not work if just copy pasted and nothing.

Comment: Thanks for that. Howewer, next time, please don't upload ZIP but include all relevant details in the answer. Don't overuse screenshots, because it's not possible to copy text from them.

Comment: How do you get it to create that launch.json file for cpp? My VSCode has never done this. It creates a launch.json file with an empty configurations array. It's always done this. I've never gotten it to auto-create one for C or C++. I've deleted the launch.json file as others have suggested, but the next time I select GDB, it just recreates another launch.json file with empty configurations.

Comment: @BryanWilliams Yeah, I get it. `launch.json` is not created anymore unless wished explicitly to have one. I deleted `.vscode` and press `F5` at one of my opened programs in VS Code for clarity. I found `tasks.json` generated by the editor intended to activate debugging. **Many things about VS Code have now changed.** Look at the answer date. I don't have time to keep updating one of my answers without a decent number of votes.

Answer (score -2):

Just add `externalConsole": true` to you configuration in launch.json.

For example:

**launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(Windows) Launch",
      "type": "cppvsdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": true,
      "preLaunchTask": "cl.exe build active file",
    }
  ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{ 
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "cl.exe build active file",
      "command": "cl.exe",
      "args": [
        "/Zi",
        "/EHsc",
        "/Fe:",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "${file}"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": ["$msCompile"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
    }
  ]
}
```