# How do I make vs code put the output of my c program in TERMINAL panel?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to build and run C code with vscode on windows 10.

I've gone through the [vscode doc for mingw configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw), followed the steps there and managed to run a .c file with vscode.

[image]

However, there's still an issue yet.

each time run my program via "Run | Run Without Debugging", the panel switches automatically to "TERMINAL"

[image]

So I have to switch to the DEBUG CONSOLE manually each time I run the code, which is tediously boring.

Is there a way to keep the "DEBUG CONSOLE" panel active or show the output of my program in "TERMINAL" panel

I also tried the suggestion in another [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62068398/where-is-my-output-when-debugging-c-code-in-visual-studio-code), but it doesn't work for me.

## tasks.json

Here is my tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "E:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: E:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

## launch.json

Here is my launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "E:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I make vs code put the output of my c program in TERMINAL panel?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_externalconsole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) with some simple configuration.

1. Install [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner).
2. Type `Ctrl + Shift + P`
3. Search and open `Open Settings(JSON)`
4. Add the following json snippets to your settings.json:

```json
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true
```

5. Every time you want to run your c code, just type the icon from the upper right corner that **Code Runner** provide.

For step 4, you can also open vscode settings and change it on GUI.

[image: Picture for settings you should change manually.]